# how to apply @ControllerAdvice in intellij idea?

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, exception, compiler-errors

i am working with intellij idea.
and i plan to make use of `@ControllerAdvice` to handle exceptions.
then intellij reports "`unhandled exception`", because i don't have a try-catch block in my code. then how to solve it? there must be a way.

Comment: I don't think you can ignore it in IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: maybe i need to edit my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not going to handle the checked exceptions with a try catch, you'll need to rethrow the exception in the method signature.  This will force the method that calls that method to handle the exception

```
public void someMethod() throws IOException {

}
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/

Comment: it works. However, the ExceptionHandler can only catch Exception thrown by controller layer, those which thrown by service layer can never be caught, wherever my ExceptionHandler is.

Comment: you should create custom exception (ex UserServiceException) to be thrown in you service layer when the original exception occurs.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29731353/what-are-the-best-practices-to-handle-exception-at-controller-service-and-dao-l

Answer (score 0):

Annotations can not affect language semantics. You may use `@ControllerAdvice` to handle exceptions at runtime, but they must be declared for the code to be accepted by the Java compiler.