# Spring+JPA EntityManager injected in service and dao

Tags: java, spring, jpa, autowired

I'm working with **Spring + JPA** (with hibernate as JPA provider) using services and dao.

I'd like to inject the JPA `EntityManager` in both service and dao, with the service managing the transactions and the dao managing the object persistence.

The dao is `@Autowired` in the service and the `EntityManager` is injected both in Service and Dao, with `@Autowired`.

In this way am I guaranteed to inject the same `EntityManager` both in the Service and in the dao ?

Comment: @shazin : how can you configure JPA EntityManager bean to be singleton or prototype ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can inject EntityManager using @PersistenceContext which  will inject shared EntityManager managed by Spring.
But i think you should reconsider your approach of having EM in service class as well.

Also look here : [Doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-jpa)

As OP's comments updating :
you can have EntityManager only in DAO classes but make those to-be atomic dao calls in same service method and make it transactional. Check out [Two Dao atomic calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3886909/where-should-transactional-be-place-service-layer-or-dao)

Comment: The point is that I have let's say one dao or more which are in charge to persist my entities. I need a service which handle the transaction. If I do it in the daos I could have dirty transactions in case of errors. How can I manage it otherwise ?

Comment: @Massimo you can have EntityManager only in DAO classes but make those to-be atominc dao calls in same service method and make it transactional.Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3886909/where-should-transactional-be-place-service-layer-or-dao

Comment: Thanks it's what I need, please update your answer so I will mark as solution

Answer (score 1):

EntityManager is initialized as a Singleton bean and so you don't have to worry as long as you make sure you wire the correct EntityManager bean in case when you have 2 or more configured in your application .

```
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "<persistent-unit-name>")
    private EntityManager entityManager;


  <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" >
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="<persistent-unit-name>" />
    ...
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `@PersistenceContext` annotation

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

Take a look at this [link](http://tomee.apache.org/examples-trunk/injection-of-entitymanager/README.html) for more info. Also look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/PersistenceContext.html) for all the possible options you have with this annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Its totally wrong way but,
all your EntityManager Instances will create with EntityManagerFactoryBean.
If you have created this @Bean, it doesn't guarantee you have the same instance of EntityManager .