# Spring with JPA pure approch

Tags: spring, jpa-2.0, hibernate3

I have a problem with Spring and JPA. Basically I try to use JPA with Spring with a pure approach, or better, without explicit references in the code to Spring framework with the exception of the @Transactional. So I wanted to know where wrong.
My persistence.xml is:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="fb-persistence" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">  
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <class>it.synclab.fb.jpa.entity.Plugin</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>
            <!-- da utilizzare solo in caso di creazione dello schema <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>-->
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>  
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>  
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="flussibatch"/>  
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="caposele"/>  
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE"/> 
        </properties>
   </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

My applicationContext is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd">

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="fb-persistence" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
    <bean name="pluginDao" class="it.synclab.fb.jpa.dao.impl.PluginDaoImpl" />
</beans>
```

my DAO interface is:

```
import it.synclab.fb.jpa.entity.Plugin;

public interface PluginDao {

    public Plugin load (int id);

    public void save(Plugin plg);
}
```

and my implementation is:

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import it.synclab.fb.jpa.entity.Plugin;


public class PluginDaoImpl implements PluginDao {

    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @PersistenceContext (unitName="fb-persistence")
    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    @Override
    public Plugin load(int id) {
        return entityManager.find(Plugin.class, id);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void save(Plugin plg) {
        entityManager.persist(plg);     
    }
}
```

This is my "horror":

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: fb-persistence] Unable to configure EntityManagerFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:563)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at it.synclab.fb.jpa.test.PluginTest.main(PluginTest.java:26)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: fb-persistence] Unable to configure EntityManagerFactory
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:378)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:56)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:48)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:92)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: it.synclab.fb.jpa.entity.StoreFileGet.idTransaction in it.synclab.fb.jpa.entity.Transaction.listStoreFileGet
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindStarToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:685)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder$1.secondPass(CollectionBinder.java:645)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.CollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass(CollectionSecondPass.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.originalSecondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1689)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1396)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildMappings(Configuration.java:1348)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildMappings(Ejb3Configuration.java:1522)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EventListenerConfigurator.configure(EventListenerConfigurator.java:193)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:1100)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:282)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:366)
    ... 18 more
```

Comment: The exception says that you hibernate mapping in incorrect, there's no problem in spring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an
>   unknown target entity property:
>   it.synclab.fb.jpa.entity.StoreFileGet.idTransaction in
>   it.synclab.fb.jpa.entity.Transaction.listStoreFileGet

This means that in your entity you have an annotation like this

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="something")
```

In this case, "something" has to be the name of the relevant field of the other entity.

Comment: you are so quick to post the answer ;)

Comment: Thanks, perhaps from exhaustion did not read the horror: P Now that we have, can I ask if I did everything right? That is, in any case however I need to define a class attribute as an EntityManager?

Comment: Friends, I posted the code that does not commit when calling the save method, why?

Comment: @giulius a) please post a new question b) you should probably not mark dao methods `@Transactional`. Transactions should be started in the service layer, not the dao layer. (see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1079114/342852) and many others)

Answer (score 0):

You have only put the `it.synclab.fb.jpa.entity.Plugin` entity in your persistence.xml, but this entity has an association to another entity (`it.synclab.fb.jpa.entity.StoreFileGet`), which is not listed. All the entities must be listed.