# Wrap transactions over existing transactional methods?

Tags: java, spring

If I have a basic Dao class that is marked as `@Transactional` on class level, this will cause every call of the Dao to run in it's own transaction.

What if I create a method somewhere which uses multiple calls to different dao methods? Will each of these calls run in its own transaction, or will the transaction be wrapped around?

```
@Service
@Transactional
class BaseDao<T> {
    //each of these methods will run in a transaction
    public void save(T entity) { }
    public void update(T entity) { }
}

@Service
class PersonFacade() {
    //will this "wrapp" the transaction?
    @Transactional
    void update() {
        dao.find();
        dao.update();
    }
}
```

If it is wrapped, would you consider it then a good practice having the `@Transactional` annotation on a generic Dao class, so that the dao might be used directly as `@Autowired BaseDao<Person>` to manage CRUD operations? And only if needed, create facades that wrap up multiple crud calls that need to run within a single transaction?

Or should I remove that transactional from the base dao better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wrap both calls into a method that is also marked @Transactional, then there will be just one transaction to span everything.

I think DAO classes should not have @Transactional annotations. Put those into a Service class that provides "business methods". Only those will know which DAO method calls (from possibly multiple entities) to compose into meaningful transactions.

See also [Where does the @Transactional annotation belong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079114/spring-transactional-annotation-best-practice)