# Best practice for commitment control using RESTful APIs

Tags: sql, rest, commit, restful-architecture

We are currently designing an application using RESTful APIs to communicate with the DB.  Our DB is a normalized structure, with upwards of 7 table representing a single application data point with an API for each DB entity.

What I am struggling with is how to institute commitment control over these tables.  Ideally, I would like to call each API from my API controller, but that would make the commit scope to a table level, and make the application control rollbacks.  This is not ideal as this would mean that we are in essence doing dirty writes.

What is the best practice to use RESTful APIs and still have teh DB perform commitment control?

Answer (score 1):

The model that you expose as a group of RESTful resources need not be the same as the model that the database uses. For example, you can use RESTful manipulation to build up a “change description” resource (local to the user's session) that is then applied to the database in one commit. The change description is complex, but there are no problems with dirty writes because all the user is changing a private world until they choose that they're going to commit to it.

If you think of a web-based model (useful with REST!) then this is like filling out a complicated order form in multiple stages. The company from which you are buying happily lets you fill out the form, storing values as necessary, but doesn't commit to actually fulfilling the order and charging your credit card until you say that it is all ready to go. I'm sure you can apply the same principle to other complex modifications.

One key thing though; if the commitment is not idempotent (i.e., if you commit it twice, different things happen) it ***must*** be a POST. That's probably a good idea in your scenario anyway, since I'd guess you want to remove the “building up an action description” resource on successful POSTing. (Yes, we'd still be following the “web form” model.)

---

I do think you want to carefully consider the complexity of your models though. It's a useful exercise to make things as simple as possible (no simpler though) where “simple” involves keeping the number of *concepts* down. If you have lots of things, but they all work exactly the same way, they're actually pretty simple. (Increasing the number of address lines in a customer record doesn't really increase the complexity very much.) The good thing about REST is that it uses very few concepts, and they're concepts that lots of people are familiar with from the web.

Answer (score 0):

Implement the controller you want for your RESTful services. The controller does little more than call through to a service layer where your transactions are managed. The service layer coordinates access to the various tables by whatever DAOs need to cooperate together--the DAOs do not need to be concerned with the transaction boundaries. If you happen to be a Spring user, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079114/spring-transactional-annotation-best-practice) thread may be of help.