# Is it possible to invoke transactional method from non transactional method in Spring?

Tags: java, spring

Suppose I have a Repository class.

```
@Repository
class MyRepository {

    @Transactional
    void method1 () {
        // some logic here
    }

    void method2 () {
        // some logic here
        method1();
        // some logic here
    }
}
```

Is it possible to do that in Spring? And how this works?

Comment: That particular example is a self-call and won't work with the usual proxy AOP.

Comment: And how can I make it work?

Comment: Usually the controller is a non-transactional class that invokes the layer service, that is a good habit to have transactional methods inside. I don't see problems in it, if your problems requires this behaviour you can do it without problems.

Comment: But my code doesn't work due to the reason described by @chrylis. I believe there is some hack how to make it work with non-standard proxy mechanism.

Comment: I think there is a way to make it work by adding `@Autowired
  private ApplicationContext context;` to your repository and then when you call `method1` from `method2` you do it like this `((MyRepository)context.getBean(getClass())).method1()`. I would advise against this though.

Comment: From Spring docs: When using proxies, the Transactional annotation should only be applied to methods with public visibility. If you do annotate protected, private or package-visible methods with the Transactional annotation, no error will be raised, but the annotated method will not exhibit the configured transactional settings. Consider the use of AspectJ (see below) if you need to annotate non-public methods.

Comment: Does the second method always call the first one? Usually? Seldom?

Answer (score 8):

This does not work, since this a *self call*. See
[Spring @Transaction method call by the method within the same class, does not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423972/spring-transaction-method-call-by-the-method-within-the-same-class-does-not-wo)

Depending on your application and its responsibilities, you could create another bean for `method2()`. 
Apart from that, DAO methods should usually not be annotated `@Transactional`. See
[Where does the @Transactional annotation belong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079114/spring-transactional-annotation-best-practice)

Comment: it would be possible to make it work using org.springframework.aop.framework.AopContext ... but it is recommended not to use this.

Answer (score 2):

You should use self injection to call a `Transactional` method from a non `Transactional` one as in Spring you can't simply call `@Transactional` method from the same instance because of AOP-proxy thing

```
@Repository
class MyRepository {

    @Autowired
    MyRepository selfTxMyRepository;

    @Transactional
    void method1 () {
        // some logic here
    }

    void method2 () {
        // some logic here
        selfTxMyRepository.method1();
        // some logic here
    }
}
```

See some explanation here: https://vladmihalcea.com/the-open-session-in-view-anti-pattern/

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that because Spring wraps methods that will be called from another class (service). If you call annotated methods **from withing the same class**, Spring will do nothing as it cannot wrap them.

Answer (score 1):

This will not work because the method will go out of the scope of `@Transaction` when you will call the `method2`. But you can apply a hack and call `method2` using `this` from `method1` in the following way.

```
this.method2();
```