# Java Spring: How to avoid using call @Transactional method from the neighboring non-transactional method?

Tags: java, spring, consistency

#### Desc

I'm working on the Java Spring project.
I've faced the behavior "transaction rollback doesn't work when calling from the same class".

- My IDE (IDEA) doesn't highlight it.
- The compiler doesn't throw an exception.
- The project is very big, and our team is big, and it is very easy to make this mistake.

### The question

**How to strictly avoid this mistake in a big project?**
I wonder - maybe there is an automated solution to not build a project with such mistakes?

#### Example:

```java
@Service
class MyServiceImpl {
    @Transactional(rollbackFor=Exception.class)
    void method1 () { // direct call works fine.
    }
    void method2 () {
      method1(); // the same class call won't be transactional. Rollback won't work.
    }
}
```

Manual solutions are already discovered there:

- [Is it possible to invoke transactional method from non transactional method in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30868829/3468202)
- [Spring @Transaction method call by the method within the same class, does not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3423972/3468202)
- etc...

Any suggestions and ideas?