# @Transactional annotation on service layer

Tags: java, spring, transactions, java-annotations

I have a DAO class where I have 2 methods annotated with the Spring `@Transactional` annotations, as follows:

```
public class ClassDAO {
    @Transactional
    public void save() throws Exception {

    }

    @Transactional
    public void save2() {

    }
}
```

I want those 2 methods to be part of the same transaction so if any method fails, the whole transaction is rolled back.

These methods are being called from the service layer, as follows:
    @Autowired
    private ClassDAO dao;

```
@Transactional
public void processDAO() {
    dao.save();
    dao.save2();
}
```

I'm using `@Transactional` annotations on service layer since I've read this is the best approach, but on the other hand I've read `@Transactional` attribute works only when calling an annotated method on a reference obtained from applicationContext, so if this is true, that would explain why the `@Transactional` annotation is not working on the service layer.

I have one questions:

If `@Transactiona`l attribute works only when calling an annotated method on a reference obtained from applicationContext, then how is it that it is a good practice to place Transactional annotation on service layer?

Thanks and best regards.

Comment: What does mean by not working? any exception/error?

Comment: If any RuntimeException is thrown in save2() method, save1() is not being rolled back, that makes me think a transaction has not been started.

If instead of doing this, I create a public and transactional method in the DAO class that calls save1 and save2, and call this new DAO method from the service class, then a transaction is started.

Comment: @Brad I think this question helps you http://stackoverflow.com/q/1079114/4934505

Comment: Your dao shouldn't be transactional so remove the `@Transactional` from the dao. If you don't have a transaction you will get a nice exception, which basically indicates an issues with your configuration. And I guess you have a component scan in place that is scanning for the same components twice.