# Spring Transaction: What will happen if I don't give @Transaction annotation on method

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jpa, transactions

I am using Spring-Boot, Spring Rest Controller and Spring Data JPA. If I don't specify @Transaction then also record get's created but I will like to understand how it happens.My understanding is that Spring by default adds a transaction with default parameters but not sure where it adds is it add Service layer or at Repository.

```
 public interface CustomerRepository extends CrudRepository<Customer, Long> {

    List<Customer> findByLastName(String lastName);
 }

 @Service
 public class CustomerServiceImpl implements CustomerService> {

   List<Customer> findByLastName(String lastName){
     //read operation
    }

 // What will happen if @Transaction is missing. How record get's created without the annotation
  public Customer insert(Customer customer){
  // insert operations
   }
 }
```

Comment: voted because I have same question and take a long time to find the answer.

Comment: Imho, Spring shouldn't add any tx behavior. What you'll get with traditional RDBMS is 'auto-commit' execution mode, where each SQL statement executing in its own separate transaction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spring Data JPA adds the @Transactional annotation at the Repository layer specifically in the class SimpleJpaRepository.This is the base Repository class which is extended for all Spring Data JPA repositories

e.g

```
/*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository#save(java.lang.Object)
     */
    @Transactional
    public <S extends T> S save(S entity) {

        if (entityInformation.isNew(entity)) {
            em.persist(entity);
            return entity;
        } else {
            return em.merge(entity);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Although Spring add automatically the `@Transactional` annotation at DAO layer, it is not the correct place nor correct behavior. The annotation must be located at service layer, there is an answered question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1079114/1917237).