# Can I place the @Transactional annotation to an entity class?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, activerecord, transactional

I am trying the [Active Record](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html) pattern using Spring and Hibernate framework. Below is the description of this pattern:

> An object carries both data and behavior. Much of this data is persistent and needs to be stored in a database. Active Record uses the most obvious approach, putting data access logic in the domain object. This way all people know how to read and write their data to and from the database.

So, I removed the traditional `Service` class and moved its logic and the `@Transactional` annotation to the entity class. But when I run my application again, the following exception was thrown.

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:133)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:454)
    weibo.datasource.UserDao.save(UserDao.java:17)
    weibo.domain.User.register(User.java:32)
    weibo.web.UserController.register(UserController.java:29)
```

**Source Code**

The `UserController` class:

```
@PostMapping("/users/register")
public String register(@RequestParam("username") String username,
                       @RequestParam("password") String password) {
    User user = new User(userDao, username, password);
    user.register();
    return "redirect:/users/login";
}
```

The `User` entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="USERS")
@Transactional
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String password;

    @Transient
    private UserDao userDao;

    public User() {}
    public User(UserDao userDao, String username, String password) {
        ...
    }

    public void register() {
        userDao.save(this);
    }
}
```

The `UserDao` class. No `@Transactional` annotated.

```
public UserDao(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}
public void save(User user) {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(user);
}
```

Why?

**UPDATE**

As @cristianhh said, the `@Transactional` annotation must be used in a **Spring-Managed** bean. However, the entity class is not.

Comment: no the @Transactional has to be on your UserDao class.

Comment: @EssexBoy In the traditional `Controller-Service-Dao` implementation, it'd better to add this annotation to the `Service` class instead of the `Dao` class.  please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079114/where-does-the-transactional-annotation-belong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, while `@Transactional` is managed by Spring, `@Entity` is managed by Hibernate.

Hibernate beans are not managed by Spring and respectively not wrappable by the `@Transactional` annotation.

You can however, use `@Transactional` in the service/repository layer and wrap a function sending the entity's data access object (DAO).

Comment: Another question: I moved the annotation to the `UserController` class, but the same exception thrown. Why?

Comment: Of course it's not a good practice, I just want to know the reason in term of source code.

Comment: @walsh is your `UserController` class marked with the `@Controller` annotation?

Comment: Yes. I add the `@Controller` to annotate `UserController` class.