# Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; EntityManager is closed

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, hibernate, jpa

I searched the internet up and down for this the last few days and tried all I could think of. I consider myself out of options now.

In a java 8 spring boot rest application I have a

**JPA repository:**

```
@Transactional
public interface PageRepository extends JpaRepository<ListPage, Long> {

    static final String CLAUSE_AND_PAGE_NR = " and lp.pageNumber = :pageNumber";
    static final String BY_LIST_ID = "from ListPage lp inner join lp.listInstance li where li.objectId = :listId";
    static final String FIND_CONTENT = "select lp.content ";

    @Query(value = FIND_CONTENT + BY_LIST_ID + CLAUSE_AND_PAGE_NR)
    public String findContentByListIdAndPageNumber(@Param("listId") final Long listId, @Param("pageNumber") final Integer pageNumber);    
}
```

**The controller:**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/download")
public class DownloadController {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DownloadController.class);

    @Resource
    ListRepository listRepository;

    @Resource
    PageRepository pageRepository;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/list/{id}/browse-txt", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces= MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> getListAsSingleFileBrowseTxt(@PathVariable(value="id") Long listId,
                                                                            HttpServletResponse response,
                                                                            HttpServletRequest request) {


        ListInstance list = listRepository.findOne(listId);
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + renameFileExtension(list.getFileName(),".TXT"));
        response.setHeader("content-type", "text/plain");


        return getResponse(auth.getCorporateKey(), list);
    }

    private ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> getResponse (String corporateKey, ListInstance list) {

        Long listId = list.getObjectId();

        StreamingResponseBody responseBody = out -> {

            Integer pageCount = pageRepository.countByListId(listId);

            long bytesBuffered = 0;
            ByteArrayOutputStream buff = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            String pageString;
            byte[] pageBytes;
            for (Integer i = 1; i <= pageCount; i++) {

                try {
                    pageString = pageRepository.findContentByListIdAndPageNumber(listId, i);

                    buff.write(pageBytes);
                    bytesBuffered += buff.size();
                    if (bytesBuffered > 1024) { //flush after 1KB
                        bytesBuffered = 0;
                        out.write(buff.toByteArray());
                        out.flush();
                        buff.reset();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    logger.error("error writing lazy buffer: page " + i + " of list " + listId, e);
                }
            }
            out.write(buff.toByteArray());
            out.flush();
        };

        return new ResponseEntity(responseBody, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

When I call the controller everything works as expected. I see in the browser the pages coming in as chunks of 1k. That's what I wanted,-lazy load of large content.

But out of a sudden (and not always at the same page) it crashes with: 
**org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManager is closed**

I understand, that this happens because the JPA repository operates in a different thread, where the thread the repository was created in, has finished (I tried that reading loop in a single thread and that worked).

**Question for me is:**
How can I prevent the JPA connection (whatever I should call it) from vanishing in the different thread?

Someone please give me another hint.

greetings

S.

Answer (score 0):

The exception is clearly saying `EntityManager is closed`.

There are following things you can do

1. move `getResponse (...)` method to some service class and annotate the method with @transactional. Call this method from your controller. Remove @Transactional from PageRepository interface. Its really doesn't matter but it is recommended. To understand more please find the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079114/where-does-the-transactional-annotation-belong)
2. **Important** : `pageString = pageRepository.findContentByListIdAndPageNumber(listId, i);` Here you are hitting DB for each pageNumber, so there that many transactions will happen. Modify your code just to do one `in` query by passing `list of page numbers`. That way there will be only one transaction to the DB.

Just try once these changes and please let us know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I could solve it:

Add this function to the **JPA repository**

```
@Query(value = FIND_CONTENT + BY_LIST_ID + CLAUSE_ORDER_BY_PAGE_NR)
@QueryHints(value = @QueryHint(name = HINT_FETCH_SIZE, value = "0"))
public Stream<String> streamAllPageContentByListID(@Param("listId") final Long listId);
```

And this will be the **Controller**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/download")
public class DownloadController {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DownloadController.class);

    @Resource
    ListRepository listRepository;

    @Resource
    PageRepository pageRepository;

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    @RequestMapping(value = "/list/{id}/browse-txt", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces= MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> getListAsSingleFileBrowseTxt(@PathVariable(value="id") Long listId,
                                                                            HttpServletResponse response,
                                                                            HttpServletRequest request) {


        ListInstance list = listRepository.findOne(listId);
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + renameFileExtension(list.getFileName(),".TXT"));
        response.setHeader("content-type", "text/plain");


        return getResponse(response, auth.getCorporateKey(), list);
    }

    protected ResponseEntity getResponse (HttpServletResponse response, String corporateKey, ListInstance list) {

        Long listId = list.getObjectId();

        try {
            try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {                

                try (Stream<String> pageStream = pageRepository.streamAllPageContentByListID(listId)) {

                    pageStream.forEach(page -> {
                        out.write(page);
                    });
                    out.flush();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("error writing lazy buffer of list " + listId, e);
            return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }

        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

A JPA repository will never work in a different thread. A final hint came from this side http://knes1.github.io/blog/2015/2015-10-19-streaming-mysql-results-using-java8-streams-and-spring-data.html

Solution works perfect so far. The speed of the lazy load is stunning.