# How to resolve 'No transaction is currently active' in spring, even after using @transactional annotation?

Tags: java, spring, transactions

```
//--Service class--

@Service
public class myService implements myInterface {

    @Autowired
    private MyDao myDao;

    //some code
    myDao.updateMethod(/*some arguments*/);
    //some code   
}

//--Dao class--

@Repository
public class MyDao {

    @Transactional(transactionManager = sample_a)
    public void updateMethod(/*some arguments*/){
        newUpdateMethod(/*some arguments*/);
    }
    @Transactional(transactionManager = sample_a)
    public void newUpdateMethod(/*some arguments*/){
        /* Actual call to DB taking place */
    }

}
```

When I call updateMethod from service class it is giving transaction related exception- **InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException - No transaction is currently active**, Am I using `@Transactional` in right way? I also read somewhere `@Transactional` should not be used in class with `@Repository` annotation, but I have other methods with `@Transactional` in Dao class and they are working fine.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079114/where-does-the-transactional-annotation-belong

Comment: When asking about an exception, you need to post the actual code causing it, and its complete and exact stack trace. Debugging partial pseudo-code is impossible.

Comment: @JBNizet The code and stack trace is complicated for me and big to put here. Can you give your views about the flow of the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above code is working fine, the problem was in transactional manager. I was using a different transactional manager. The table that I was using to update data was in different database.